# Local stack packages

Tags: cabal, haskell-stack

I've got a number of local stack packages, in the usual form of a directory with a `stack.yaml` file, and `PackageName.cabal`, and a `src` directory.

I'd like to have a local stack packages depend on another local stack package, preferably without this option being carried with the package if I do ever upload it to Hackage (at which point the local package will make no sense).

A directory with symbolic links to all my local stackage packages and a global override to search that directory first will be fine, but also specifying the required local packages on a per package basis is also fine, as long as this configuration options don't get carried alone if I package it up with Hackage.

How can I achieve this? Links to the appropriate section in the stack docs is fine, and perhaps the answer is in there and I just can't find it.

Comment: Would a simple [multi-package project](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#multi-package-projects) work, like for example [this one](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant)?

Comment: The [`packages` section](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages) in your stack.yaml can also contain filepaths like `../other-lib`.